# Python Tkinter: Abort Radio Button in command callback

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I'm trying to provide a little bit of extra safety on one of the radio buttons in my Tkinter application. I have a set of radio buttons to switch between bit depths on a bitmap editor, and one of the modes modifies the palette, so I want to check with the user before performing the action. Here's a quick demo I wrote to illustrate the problem:

```python
# Radio Button Abort Test
# Mikumiku747 2019-12-30

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb

class Application():

    def __init__(self):
        # Create widgets
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.dummyvar = tk.IntVar(self.root, value=1)
        self.radio1 = tk.Radiobutton(self.root, text="Option 1 (Safe)",
                                     command=lambda: self.safecallback(1),
                                     var=self.dummyvar, value=1)
        self.radio2 = tk.Radiobutton(self.root, text="Option 2 (Safe)",
                                     command=lambda: self.safecallback(2),
                                     var=self.dummyvar, value=2)
        self.radio3 = tk.Radiobutton(self.root, text="Option 3 (Dangerous)",
                                     command=lambda: self.dangercallback(3),
                                     var=self.dummyvar, value=3)
        # Widget Layout
        self.radio1.pack()
        self.radio2.pack()
        self.radio3.pack()

    def safecallback(self, value):
        print("Safe Callback with value", value)

    def dangercallback(self, value):
        print("Dangerous callback, asking for confirmation:")
        # We need to confirm with the user before doing anything which would 
        answer = tkmb.askyesno("Perform dangerous action",
                               "Are you sure you want to perform this action? Unsaved data may be lost!")
        if answer:
            print("User confirmed, clear things out.")
        else:
            return
```

The problem is that after clicking on option 3, even if the user presses no on the dialog, the third option will still be selected. This could be confusing since these radio buttons also convey information about the state of the editor to the user. Is there an easy way to undo the selection or do I have to keep track of the previous value of the variable myself?

Comment: ***"undo the selection"***: Use [Radiobutton.deselect-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm#Tkinter.Radiobutton.deselect-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to set your `dummyvar` to 0 in order to unselect all three options of the `Radiobutton'. Here is the modification for the end of your code:

```
    if answer:
        print("User confirmed, clear things out.")
    else:
        self.dummyvar.set(0)
```